# Edit Entry Length in Dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I’m new to using datasets in VB and I’ve been unable to find guidance on achieving the following:

Some descriptions in the dataset are too long, is there a way to take the first 10 characters of a description?

I’ve tried using:

```
dataSet.Tables("statement-data").Rows(0).Item(1) = Left(dataSet.Tables("statement-data").Rows(1).Item(1).ToString)
```

But I get a “Public Property Left As Integer has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed” error

Example Data

Dataset Table: statement-data

```
Date        Description                         Debit/Credit    Amount
01122012    Computer Equipment for North Office D           1000.00
01122012    Coffee                              D           25.68
02122012    Payment for Service                 C           1500.00
```

If anyone can help, or point me towards any good websites/guidance, that would be awesome.
Thanks
Martyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that your code is in a form (or user control). [`System.Windows.Forms.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) has a `Left` property, so your `Left` is referring to `Form.Left` instead of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left`. To get past the error, you can:

- Explicitly qualify the use of the `Left` method with `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left`
- Use the [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method instead
- Put your code in a separate class or module where `Form`'s properties won't conflict with it

Answer (score 0):

Use .NET methods, in this case [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

```
Dim firstRow = DataSet.Tables("statement-data").Rows(0)
Dim description = firstRow.Field(Of String)("Description")
If description.Length > 10 Then
    description = description.Substring(0, 10)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tim
I managed to get it to work using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left

<code> dataSet.Tables("csv-data").Rows(0).Item(1) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dataSet.Tables("csv-data").Rows(i).Item(1), 255) <code>

I'm not sure why Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left worked and Left did not.